# "The page is not redirecting properly" firefox xampp php page failed to load

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

**Update Nov 11th**

I tried to copy-paste the whole thing from [tutorialrepublic](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php), and only edited the directory to the error page and the landing page. Also, I created a table based on this code (which is **employee [id, name, address, salary]**) along with three rows of data.

So, here's how *try-update.php* looks now:

```php
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "./assets/php/connecttodb.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$name = $address = $salary = "";
$name_err = $address_err = $salary_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    
    // Validate name
    $input_name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    if(empty($input_name)){
        $name_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $name_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    } else{
        $name = $input_name;
    }
    
    // Validate address address
    $input_address = trim($_POST["address"]);
    if(empty($input_address)){
        $address_err = "Please enter an address.";     
    } else{
        $address = $input_address;
    }
    
    // Validate salary
    $input_salary = trim($_POST["salary"]);
    if(empty($input_salary)){
        $salary_err = "Please enter the salary amount.";     
    } elseif(!ctype_digit($input_salary)){
        $salary_err = "Please enter a positive integer value.";
    } else{
        $salary = $input_salary;
    }
    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($name_err) && empty($address_err) && empty($salary_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE employees SET name=?, address=?, salary=? WHERE id=?";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $param_name, $param_address, $param_salary, $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_name = $name;
            $param_address = $address;
            $param_salary = $salary;
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: /skripsi-manual/display-jenispembayaran.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
         
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($connect);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);
        
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $name = $row["name"];
                    $address = $row["address"];
                    $salary = $row["salary"];
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: /skripsi-manual/try-errorpage.php");
                    exit();
                }
                
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        
        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: /skripsi-manual/try-errorpage.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Update Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Update Record</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>Please edit the input values and submit to update the record.</p>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($name_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $name_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($address_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <textarea name="address" class="form-control"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $address_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($salary_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Salary</label>
                            <input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $salary; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $salary_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And still, it redirects me straight to the error page.
Could you show me what's wrong with this code and how to solve it?

If it helps, I've copy-edited the *Read* section in [tutorialrepublic](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php) , and it works without much issue.

Thank you in advance.

---

I'm creating a page to update data on my database. Copy-edited the php code and `<head>` from [this page](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php)

PHP file and html form are in the same file. Except for the file to connect to database.

Here is the form (try-update.php):

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Update Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Update Record</h2>
                    </div>

                    <?php
// Include config file
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once './assets/php/connecttodb.php';
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$id_jenispembayaran = $nama_jenispembayaran = "";
$id_jenispembayaran_err = $nama_jenispembayaran_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["id_jenispembayaran"]) && !empty($_POST["id_jenispembayaran"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["id_jenispembayaran"];
    
    // Validate name
    $input_nama = trim($_POST["nama_jenispembayaran"]);
    if(empty($input_nama)){
        $nama_jenispembayaran_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_nama, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $nama_jenispembayaran_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    } else{
        $nama_jenispembayaran = $input_nama;
    }
    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($nama_jenispembayaran_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE jenispembayaran SET nama_jenispembayaran=? WHERE id_jenispembayaran=?";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $param_nama_jenispembayaran, $param_id_jenispembayaran);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_nama_jenispembayaran = $nama_jenispembayaran;
            $param_id_jenispembayaran = $id_jenispembayaran;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: /skripsi-manual/display-jenispembayaran.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
         
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($connect);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id_jenispembayaran"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id_jenispembayaran"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id_jenispembayaran =  trim($_GET["id_jenispembayaran"]);
        
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM jenispembayaran WHERE id_jenispembayaran = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id_jenispembayaran);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_id_jenispembayaran = $id_jenispembayaran;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $id_jenispembayaran = $row["id_jenispembayaran"];
                    $nama_jenispembayaran = $row["nama_jenispembayaran"];
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: /skripsi-manual/try-update.php");
                    exit();
                }
                
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        
        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: /skripsi-manual/try-update.php");
        echo "somethings's wrong";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
                    <p>Please edit the input values and submit to update the record.</p>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
                    <label for="id_jenisPembayaran">Kode Jenis Pembayaran:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="id_jenisPembayaran" value="<?php echo $id_jenisPembayaran;?>">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="nama_jenisPembayaran">Nama Jenis Pembayaran:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nama_jenisPembayaran" value="<?php echo $nama_jenisPembayaran;?>">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit">Masukkan</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my connection file (connecttodb.php):

```php
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$serverName = 'localhost';
$dbUserName = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'sip-krl';
 
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$connect = mysqli_connect($serverName, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbName);
 
// Check connection
if($connect === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

This form is supposed to select one *jenispembayaran* based on the id (which is *id_jenispembayaran*), puts it on the  so users could edit it, and when they click "Submit", the page will change the data on the database, then redirects to *display-jenispembayaran.php*, where all *jenispembayaran* is displayed. If something went wrong, it should reload *try-update.php* and write what the error is.

Problem is, with this code, all I got is either this:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly 
>  Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. 
>  This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Or, when I change the header() in this:

```php
} else{
    // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
   header("location: /skripsi-manual/try-update.php");
   echo "somethings's wrong";
   exit();
   }
  }
?>
```

into this:

```php
} else{
    // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
   header("location: /skripsi-manual/display-jenispembayaran.php");
   echo "somethings's wrong";
   exit();
   }
  }
?>
```

This form directs me to *display-jenispembayaran.php*, or other pages I typed in. No echo *'something's wrong'* whatsoever in *display-jenispembayaran.php*

After several attempts and observations, I concluded the error is that my page doesn't contain **id parameter** (do please correct me if I'm wrong). So, I tried to give id parameters by changing the php code into this:

```php
// Processing form data when form is submitted
  if(isset($_POST["id_jenispembayaran"]) && !empty($_POST["id_jenispembayaran"])){
      // Get hidden input value
      $id = $_POST["id_jenispembayaran"];
                            
      // Validate name and id
      $input_id = trim($_POST["id_jenispembayaran"]);
      if(empty($input_id)){
      $id_jenispembayaran_err = "Please enter an id.";
      } elseif(!filter_var($input_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
      $id_jenispembayaran_err = "Please enter a valid id.";
      } else{
      $id_jenispembayaran = $input_id;
      }
      $input_nama = trim($_POST["nama_jenispembayaran"]);
      if(empty($input_nama)){
      $nama_jenispembayaran_err = "Please enter a name.";
      } elseif(!filter_var($input_nama, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
      $nama_jenispembayaran_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
      } else{
      $nama_jenispembayaran = $input_nama;
      }
                            
       // Check input errors before inserting in database
       if(!empty($nama_jenispembayaran_err)){
       // Prepare an update statement
       $sql = "UPDATE jenispembayaran SET nama_jenispembayaran=? WHERE id_jenispembayaran=?";
                                
       if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)){
       // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $param_nama_jenispembayaran, $param_id_jenispembayaran);
                                    
      // Set parameters
      $param_nama_jenispembayaran = $nama_jenispembayaran;
      $param_id_jenispembayaran = $id_jenispembayaran;
                                    
      // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
      if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
      // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
      header("location: /skripsi-manual/try-update.php");
      exit();
      } else{
      echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
      }
      }
                                
      // Close statement
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      }
                            
      // Close connection
      mysqli_close($connect);
      } else{
      // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
      if(isset($_GET["id_jenispembayaran"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id_jenispembayaran"]))){
      // Get URL parameter
      $id_jenispembayaran =  trim($_GET["id_jenispembayaran"]);
                                
      // Prepare a select statement
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM jenispembayaran WHERE id_jenispembayaran = ?";
      if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)){
      // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $param_id_jenispembayaran, $param_nama_jenispembayaran);
                                    
     // Set parameters
      $param_id_jenispembayaran = $id_jenispembayaran;
      $param_nama_jenispembayaran = $nama_jenisPembayaran;
                                    
      // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
      if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                            
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                                            
         // Retrieve individual field value
        $id_jenispembayaran = $row["id_jenispembayaran"];
        $nama_jenispembayaran = $row["nama_jenispembayaran"];
        } else{
       // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
       header("location: /skripsi-manual/try-update.php");
      exit();
    }
                                        
    } else{
     echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
   }
  }
```

Still, it redirects me back to *display-jenispembayaran.php*.
I also tried placing `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` above the `<html>` tag. It doesn't give me any errors.

Anyone could show me what went wrong and how to solve them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't pass `$_GET["id_jenispembayaran"]`to your `try-update.php`, the script will just reload itself again and again. It's also meaningless to echo something after you have done a `header('location: ....')` since that redirects the client _away_ from the current page. In your `else`, the comment says _"Redirect to error page"_ but you redirect to `/skripsi-manual/try-update.php` (which I believe is itself?)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: **(which I believe is itself?)** => Yep. I'm making this page redirects back to itself plus an error message to let the users know something's wrong with their input. **It's also meaningless to echo something after...** => ooh... noted. **If you don't pass** `$_GET["id_jenispembayaran]` **to your** `try-update.php` **... again and agan** => do you mean I need to change `$_POST` to `$_GET` ? If yes, then I just did and it still didn't work.

Comment: When you redirect, it will always be a GET. When you redirect, you do that without a query string so when the page loads again, it will come to the same `else` statement that will just redirect the client to the same page again. And when that happens, it will come to the same `else` and redirect the client to itself yet another time. That will go on until the browser complains about invalid/too many redirects.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: uh... sorry. I didn't catch what you mean.

Comment: Just follow your code from the top and see what happens if you would access the page without having either `$_POST["id_jenispembayaran"]` 
 or `$_GET["id_jenispembayaran"]` set, which is the default state when you just access the page directly (like in the browser) or if you redirected the user to that page the way you're doing (since you don't add any query param when redirecting). The code should end up at: `header("location: /skripsi-manual/try-update.php");`, which makes an identical request to the same page (since you're already on `try-update.php`). I can't explain it clearer than this.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Thank you for your effort. I just tried it and this page led me straight to the error page I've added.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I also have tried to copy-pasted the whole thing from [tutorialrepublic](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php) and only edited the directory for error page and config file. I also created a table using the variables in the code. It still led me to the error page. **P.S: I've put the code in my question**